# Understanding basic evented IO between C# and NODE using EDGE.JS

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, edge.js

JavaScript is strong with me. .NET, notsomuch...

I'm trying to figure out edgeJS on NodeJS and while I've got some sense of how to patch together communication between the two I can't seem to figure out how to maintain a listener in NODE for my Edge functions to send events to. I can only seem to get my functions to fire and hand off control to Edge while the function is running, but I would like Edge to tell NODE to do something basic for starters like console.log in NODE instead of Console.Write in .NET.

Is there an example out there that can help me? The Edge documentation seems to be above my head in this regard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer - I am new to Edge JS.

But Edge Js is for in process communication not cross process. When you say you would like to call console.log in node js - what I thought you want is call an independent nodejs application from C# ? I don't think that is possible using Edge js but you can always make http call and host a web service and that is what is shown in one of the performance graph that the in process and out of process calls difference.

Quoting from InfoQ article. Which shows we are talking about in process communication where the code of ne is nested in another and not separate.

> There are two main benefits of using Edge.js to run Node.js and .NET in one process instead of splitting the application into two processes: better performance, and reduced complexity. Performance measurements of one scenario show that in-process Edge.js call from Node.js to C# is 32 times faster than the same call made using HTTP between two local processes. Dealing with a single process instead of two processes with a communication channel between them reduces the deployment and maintenance complexity you need to handle.

Comment: Hey lazy (nice handle), thanks for taking the time to share your understanding here. I think to better explain what I'm trying to do is that I have a persistent function running in Edge that talks to a hardware device (a RFID reader), and when tags are read, data is captured by Edge. I have an entire pre-existing system in Node that deals with that data, and I'd like to have Node simply listen for Edge to send that data in for handling on an event listener. Do you happen to have a link to that InfoQ article in question?

Comment: [InfoQ article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/the_edge_of_net_and_node). If there is separate program running in node can you bring that to edge. The way you could connect to out proc system is http